# Scrapy outputs blank CSV

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

`scrapy crawl raamatuvahetus -o raamatuvahetus.csv` is outputting an empty csv file. I have no idea why this is. All other Scrapy files generated by `scrapy startproject` are untouched, and all settings are left at default.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class RaamatuvahetusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'raamatuvahetus'
    start_urls = ['https://www.raamatuvahetus.ee/et/bookwished.wishall?limit=200']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath("//a[@class='b-info']/@href"):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        wishings = response.xpath("//img[@class='uimg']")
        wishings_count = 0
        if wishings:
            wishings_count = len(wishings)
            if wishings_count < 15:
                raise CloseSpider('Wishings fever than 15.')
        title = response.xpath("//article[@class='text']/h1/text()").extract_first()
        author = response.xpath("//div[@class='author']/a/text()").extract_first()
        year = response.xpath("//div[@class='year']/text()").extract_first()
        yield 
        {
            "Pealkiri": title,
            "Autor": author,
            "Aasta": year,
            "Soovid": wishings_count
        }
```

Edit: 
Solved! Heed all travelers who accost a similar complication -- fret not! I have the answers you seek.

Instead of

```
yield 
{
}
```

write

```
yield {
}
```

Comment: Did you try `scrapy crawl spider_name -o result.csv`?

Comment: Ah, accidentally wrote the wrong command in the post. Edited.

Comment: What does the logging say? Have you tried for instance: `for href in response.xpath("//a[@class='b-info']/@href").extract()`...

Comment: you might also want to consider CSS selectors that'll make things possibly easier to read... for instance... the above could be `response.css('a.b-info::attr(href)').extract()` instead... (same for the later bits...)